# Trying to use a SOQL result as an HTML div id in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, soql, html

Answer:

I figured it out (or at least worked around it). I used `document.getElementById(researcher).show;`
instead of `$$(researcher).each(function(element) element.show();`

and it works perfectly now.

I am trying to use javascript to only display data from a specific owner. Is there any way I can use the results from a SOQL query as a div id?

Here is a snippet of what I want to do:

```
<select name="r" id="r" onchange="selectResearcher()">
    <option></option>
    <option value="name">Name/option>
    <option value="name1">Name1</option>
```

```
div class="output" id="{!less.Lead_Analyst__r.LastName}"
```

here is the javascript portion of my code:

```
<script>

    function selectResearcher(){ 
        researcher = $F('r'); 
        if(researcher.length > 1) { 
            $$('div.output').each(function(element){
                element.hide();
            });
            $$(researcher).each(function(element){
                element.show();
            });
        }
        else{
            $$('div.output').each(function(element){
                element.show();
            });
        }
    }


</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I need all the data no matter what user or owner. I have a select list that uses javascript to tell which data should be displayed by getting the div id depending on what selection is made

Comment: Where are you executing that SOQL ? How's your page setup ? Without context and details it's hard to answer your question, could you update it with more info ? Possibilities are using apex tags to create divs, or composte html in JS through javascript remoting, or other options depending on what you're already doing ..

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of ways to do this, eith via JSRemoting or through an apex:repeat.  Either way you can return everything and then use **$j(".class"/"#id").hide()** if the data tag isnt the right name.  Sorta like this, sorry if this isn't super well explained, hopefully it helps.

Try using it in a data tag as such

```
<apex:repeat value="{!someGetterMethod}" var="LeadName">
    <div class="output" data-aName="{!LeadName.LastName}"> </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

then from your jquery code, if that is what you are using; you can reference it as such :

(if this is in an Apex:Repeat tag)

```
$j(".output").each(function(index, value) {

if($j(this).data('aName') == "LastNameOfSomePerson")
{
$j(this).show(); //or hide();
}

});
```

Comment: this is almost exactly what I need but I'm using javascript. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you post more of your code, I'll gladly help more if I can! :)